# Azure WebJobs QueueTrigger ignores environment when reading configuration

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-queues, queuetrigger

I have an Azure WebJobs with QueueTrigger:

```cs
public void ProcessTestQueueByTrigger(
    [QueueTrigger("test-queue", Connection = "MyCustomStorageConnection")] string queueMessage,
    int dequeueCount,
    TextWriter log)
    {
        var message = $"ProcessTestQueueByTrigger executed: {queueMessage}, dequeue: {dequeueCount}";
        log.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Where `MyCustomStorageConnection` is not the same as default jobs connection (that is why I define it in the QueueTrigger attribute). I also have two local files which defines settings for dev and prod environment: `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Production.json`.

When I start the WebJobs, I'm reading the valid configuration and settings to the `config` object

```cs
var configuration = new JobHostConfiguration
{
    DashboardConnectionString = config.GetConnectionString("AzureWebJobsDashboard"),
    StorageConnectionString = config.GetConnectionString("AzureWebJobsStorage"),
};
```

and the valid connection stored in `config.GetConnectionString("MyCustomStorageConnection")` but there is no place to set it with the host. And whenever host is started, the `QueueTrigger` is reading the value from the `appsettings.json` and totally ignores the `appsettings.Production.json`.

How can I force QueueTrigger to use the proper config or just define the value for the QueueTrigger connection string?

Comment: Hello, I want to check if you have solved the issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily by setting environment variable.

The following are the steps, on windows 10 with visual studio 2017.

1.Create a .NET core webjob(you can follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started) if not familiar), and the completed code as below:

**Program.cs:**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MySampleWebjob
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //since we have 2 .json files, we can control which .json file is to be used by setting a Environment variable. And then read the value here.
            var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            Console.WriteLine($"the environment is: "+ environment);

            var builder = new HostBuilder();
            builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddAzureStorage();
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) => {
                configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true,reloadOnChange:true);
                configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
            {
                b.AddConsole();
            })
            ;
            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                host.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Functions.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MySampleWebjob
{
        public class Functions
        {
            public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items")] string message, ILogger logger)
            {
                logger.LogInformation(message);
            }
        }    
}
```

**Then** add 2 .json files in the project: `appsettings.Production.json` and `appsettings.json`. The structure of the 2 .json files are the same, but have different storage connectiong strings.

**appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
}
```

**appsettings.Production.json:**

```
  {
      "AzureWebJobsStorage": "Another azure storage connection string"
    }
```

**Note that** in visual studio, right click each of the json file -> properties -> set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer".

**At last**, set environment variable via cmd or UI. The cmd command is `setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Production"`, then restart the visual studio if you want to use the environment variable.

So if you want to use the storage connection string from `appsettings.json`, don't need to set the environment variable. If you want to use the connection string from `appsettings.Production.json`, need to set the environment variable.

**Note that**, if you **set an environment variable** or **remove an environment variable**, remember to restart the visual studio to take effect.